# GC Warning when running PDFTK command in PHP script

Tags: php, linux, gcc, pdftk

My PHP script generates a PDF using `pdftk`. When it runs `pdftk` I get the error status `134` and the pdf is not generated. Weirdly if I run that exact same `pdftk` command in SSH shell it works.

What does the status code `134` mean? And what could be going wrong?

My command:

```
$output = '';
$status = -1;
$res = exec("cd /home/USER/public_html/app; pdftk mht1939-1-rp_spl_form_hba1c.pdf fill_form ./tmp/58c5e762113c0.fdf output ./tmp/58c5e76211451.pdf flatten verbose", $output, $status);

print($status);
var_dump($output);
```

The error output is:

```
134 
array(3) { [0]=> string(36) "GC Warning: Couldn't read /proc/stat" [1]=> string(39) "GC Warning: GC_get_nprocs() returned -1" [2]=> string(29) "Couldn't read /proc/self/stat" }
```

Note the folder `tmp` has permissions `777` and the server is a CentOS 6.8 VPS.